# How would i write a function in python using variables for a sum of exponential series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, series, exponent

I am trying to create a code in which you input a starting integer, number of terms, and the exponent. This is my current code, i have run it with just numbers, but cannot figure out how to run it with variables, that are prompted by the user.

```
def squares(s,n,e):
    for x in range(s,s+n):
        Sum=0
        Sum=sum(Sum+x**e)

s=int(input("input starting integer:"))
n=int(input("input number of terms:"))
e=int(input("input exponent:"))

print(squares(s,n,e))
```

Comment: Looks like you're solution should almost work. what problems are having?

Comment: Using `numpy`: `np.sum(np.arange(start, start+n)**e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing some of the syntax (e.g. [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum) takes an iterable, not a constant), I believe your code works:

```
def squares(s,n,e ):
    for x in range(s,s+n):
        Sum=0
        Sum+=sum([Sum, x**e])
    return Sum

s=int(input("input starting integer:")) #e.g. '9'
n=int(input("input number of terms:"))  #e.g. '4'
e=int(input("input exponent:"))         #e.g. '3'
print(squares(s,n,e))     # result: 1728
```